# Google search code in ASP.NET Master Page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I'm trying to put the following Google generated search box code into a Master page on a site:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/cse" id="cse-search-box">
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-xxxxxxxxxx:u3qsil-l6ut" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1" />
    <input type="text" name="q" size="31" />
    <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=en"></script>
```

The problem, I believe, is something to do with the form tags. I've tried putting this code inside a user control and embedding that in the master page but no luck yet...

Comment: This article can help you: [Using Google Co-op's Custom Search Engine on ASP .NET](http://codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomSearchEngine.aspx)

Comment: Alternatively, you could use javascript: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Implementing-Search-in-ASP-NET-with-Google-Custom-Search.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Do you by any chance have a "form runat=server" wrapping around where your user control is being placed?
That would cause a problem.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET likes to enclose the entire page with a Form tag, and you can't nest form tags...So move it outside of the <form runat="Server"> tag and you'll be fine.